# htaccess rewrite for generated links

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, .htaccess

[image: htacess]

Hi,

In the picture shows my htaccess rules, it blocks all requests not coming from this referer.
But the application installed sends a confirmation email after booking with a URL ending like this:

> https://website.com/index.php/appointments/index/4a501c802f0a25283ca7a

when I try to access the link from the email it blocks me because I'm not coming from the referer, I'm trying to add a rule to accept any request that includes /index.php/appointments/index/ and everything after.

Comment: "it blocks all requests not coming from this referer" - Rather curious, the code you posted appears to do the complete opposite?! Do you have other directives, or has this been edited? Please post your actual "current" code, and not a screenshot.

Comment: This is my current code the HTTP_HOST Was one of my trials

Answer (score 0):

> the picture shows my htaccess rules, it blocks all requests not coming from this referer.

The code you posted in the "screenshot" doesn't appear to do what you say it does - it seems to do the opposite? (This would seem to be your "edited/non-working" version?)

To allow only a *specific* `Referer` OR access to the URL-type as mentioned, regardless of `Referer`, you would need to do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/appointments/index/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www\.referrer\.com/url/to/allow$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Note that this does not allow direct requests (ie. no `Referer`), so some users will have problems with this. (Note that links from email clients are generally treated like direct requests.)

Generally, you should be as restrictive as possible with the regex. In your text you stated "any request that includes `/index.php/appointments/index/` and everything after". However, the example URL appears to show a 21 character hex-code.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*(index|appointments).* [NC]
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header. ie. the *hostname* being requested, not the URL-path. However, the regex you are using does not match the URL being requested anyway (it is far too general).

Comment: your method works only if they're coming from an email and the page loads with an error forbidden you cannot access this resource. what I'm trying to do is allow access to my website if you click a button from a certain website and IF your direct link has index.php/appointments/index/

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for the moment it might not be as accurate as i want to be but it works if anyone has the same question for the future:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php
RewriteRule !^(index\.php) [NC,F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^somewebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule !^ - [F,NC]
```

Downside is the user can still input website.com/index.php i dont think the referer is working but thats the closest i could ever come to.

I'm welcoming any enhancement or suggestions as far as i could understand.